# How do I filter users by status not blocked?

Tags: 7, views

I created a Drupal 7 view that displays users profile 2 fields. However if i disable the user their fields are still visible in the view. Is there a way i can filter users by their status of blocked or active?

[image]

Comment: Add filter for status and set it as active/blocked which ever you need to display.

Comment: searching for status in filter criteria comes up empty.

Comment: If it is a profile2 based View, then you have to create a relationship to the User. This should then create new filtering options based on that relationship.

Comment: i'm not entirely certain how thats done. all the way on the right under advanced and relationships i made one from indexed user to Main profile profile but i don't see any new filtering option.

Comment: Indexed user? Is this Search API?

Comment: this view box appears in a search form. it displays people related the keyword being searched

Answer (score 1):

The steps are:

View name: test
Show: Profiles
of type: All

Page title: test
Display format: table.

click "Continue & edit" button.

In the "FIELDS"

add the "Profile: User uid" field and add all fields related to the profile module.

Then add a relation in the path: Advanced-> RELATIONSHIPS

select the "Profile: User uid" field.

mark the checkbox "Require this relationship".

Click "apply (all displays)" button.

Then add a filter to "FILTER CRITERIA".

Seach and check the field: "User: Active"

We checked the checkbox: "Expose this filter to visitors, to allow them to change it"

Click "apply (all displays)" button.

Click "save" button.

Comment: this works if i create a new view but not the existing view. Profile: user uid doesnt appear

Comment: In your view, follow these steps from:     Then add a relation in the path: Advanced-> RELATIONSHIPS

Comment: under the advanced-> RELATIONSHIPS there is no Profile: User uid or anything with uid in it's name